# Updating TextBox with Model Binding after Post action occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am having an issue with an admittedly non-traditional use case of Razor and .NET Core 3.1. I have a Razor page set up with model bindings for my fields, when a user clicks a button it routes to the NonAction function to perform some potentially lengthy (user defined amount of time) calculations. I want to post to a textbox when any 1 of 3 parallel running tasks sends a message but I can't get the textbox to update on the client side with the model binding and I don't want to cause a postback every time the modelstate updates (as the parallel tasks can be messaging anywhere from 100ms to 5000ms).

I'm probably doing it wrong as I'm fairly new to Razor. The idea is that the parallel tasks use my custom  ConcurrentQueue (so I could add an event handler for when a message gets enqueued) and whenever an enqueued event fires the main thread updates the textbox.

Here's the .cshtml:

```
@page
@using AMQSimNetCore.Pages;
@model AMQSimNetCore.Pages.Producer.ProducerModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Producer";
}

<h1>Producer</h1>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>AMQ Producer</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("OnPostRunSimulator_OnClickAsync", "Producer", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="container" id="dv_ctrlsContainer" style="border-color:grey; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; margin-bottom:10px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="TalkerSelected" />
                    <label ID="lbl_talker">Generate Talker Messages</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label ID="lbl_talkerTime">Time (in ms) between generated talker messages.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="TalkerTime" width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PartInfoSelected" />
                    <label ID="lbl_partInfo">Generate PartInfo Messages</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label ID="lbl_partInfoTime">Time (in ms) between generated part info messages.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="PartInfoTime" Width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="ConfInfoSelected" />
                    <label ID="lbl_confInfo">Generate ConfInfo Messages</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label ID="lbl_confInfoTime">Time (in ms) between generated conf info messages.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="ConfInfoTime" Width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_totalSimTime">Total Time (in ms) to run Simulator</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="TotalConfTime" Width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_numSimultaneousConfs">Number of Simulatenous Conferences</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="NumSimultaneousConfs" Width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_numParts">Number of participants.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="NumParts" Width="75" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_endpoint">Choose Endpoint</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">                    
                    <select asp-for="EndpointString" class="form-control">
                        <option>xxxxxxxx</option>
                        <option>xxxxxxxx</option>
                        <option>xxxxxxxx</option>
                        <option>xxxxxxxx</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_userName">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="UserName" Width="150" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label ID="lbl_password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Password" Width="150" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="border-color:grey; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; margin-bottom:10px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text"style="height:auto; width:100% !important;" asp-for="Logger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" ID="btn_run" asp-page-handler="RunSimulator_OnClick" Width="125" value="Run Simulator" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here's the .cshtml.cs code:

```
    using Apache.NMS;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands;
using Common.Logging;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ISession = Apache.NMS.ISession;
using static AMQSimNetCore.ConcurrentQueueWithEvents<string>;

namespace AMQSimNetCore.Pages.Producer
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class ProducerModel : PageModel
    {

        public string EndpointString { get; set; }

        public bool TalkerSelected { get; set; } = true;
        public int TalkerTime { get; set; } = 1000;

        public bool PartInfoSelected { get; set; } = true;
        public int PartInfoTime { get; set; } = 1000;

        public bool ConfInfoSelected { get; set; } = true;
        public int ConfInfoTime { get; set; } = 1000;

        public int TotalConfTime { get; set; } = 60000;
        public int NumSimultaneousConfs { get; set; } = 5;
        public int NumParts { get; set; } = 2;

        public string UserName { get; set; } = "xxxxxx";
        public string Password { get; set; } = "xxxxxx";

        public string Logger { get; set; }

        private readonly ConcurrentQueueWithEvents<string> loggerText = new ConcurrentQueueWithEvents<string>();
        private ConnectionFactory factory;
        private IConnection connection;
        private IMessageProducer producer;
        private ISession sessionProducer;
        private int msgNum = 0, loopTimes = 0;
        private List<int> ConfIds = new List<int>();
        private readonly string publishTopicName = "xxxxxxx";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ConfIds = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, NumSimultaneousConfs));
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConfIds", JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(ConfIds));
        }

        [NonAction]
        public async void OnPostRunSimulator_OnClickAsync(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            loggerText.OnEnqueuedMessage += MessageEnqueued;

            bool _config = await LoadConfig(collection);

            if (!_config)
            {
                this.Response.Redirect("/Error");
            }

            if(EndpointString.Contains("xxxxxxx"))
            {
                this.factory = new ConnectionFactory("ssl://" + EndpointString + "?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000");
            }
            else
            {
                this.factory = new ConnectionFactory("failover:(ssl://" + EndpointString + "?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000)");
            }

            this.factory.AsyncSend = true;

            this.connection = factory.CreateConnection(UserName, Password);
            ((Connection)this.connection).AsyncSend = true;
            this.connection.Start();
            this.sessionProducer = this.connection.CreateSession();

            Task pt = Task.Run(() => {
                Parallel.Invoke(
                    () =>
                    {
                        CalcLoop();
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (ConfInfoSelected)
                        {

                            GenerateConfInfo(ConfIds);
                        }
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (PartInfoSelected)
                        {

                            GeneratePartInfo(ConfIds);
                        }
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (TalkerSelected)
                        {

                            GenerateTalker(ConfIds);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });

            ModelState.Clear();
            Task.WhenAll(pt);
        }

        void MessageEnqueued()
        {
            if (loggerText.TryDequeue(out string _msg))
            {
                Logger += _msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        private Task<bool> CalcLoop()
        {
            bool _finished = false;

            while (loopTimes < (this.TotalConfTime / 1000))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                loopTimes++;
            }
            return Task.FromResult(_finished);
        }

        private Task<bool> GenerateConfInfo(List<int> confIds)
        {
            bool _finished = false;

            while (loopTimes < (this.TotalConfTime / 1000))
            {
                foreach (int confId in confIds)
                {
                    var conf = new ConfInfo()
                    {
                        ConfId = confId.ToString(),
                        Active = true,
                        TalkerNotify = true
                    };

                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(m, conf);
                        ActiveMQBytesMessage msg = new ActiveMQBytesMessage();
                        msg.Content = m.ToArray();
                        msg.Properties.SetString("confid", confId.ToString());

                        Interlocked.Increment(ref msgNum);

                        msg.Properties.SetString("msgNum", msgNum.ToString());

                        msg.NMSDeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;

                        msg.NMSType = "confinfo";

                        msg.NMSTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

                        msg.ReadOnlyBody = true;

                        var topic = new ActiveMQTopic(publishTopicName + "." + confId.ToString());

                        this.producer = this.sessionProducer.CreateProducer(topic);
                        this.producer.Send(msg);

                        loggerText.Enqueue(String.Format("{0} - MsgNum {1}: Sending ConfInfo message for ConfId {2}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), msgNum.ToString(), confId.ToString()));
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(ConfInfoTime);
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(_finished);
        }

        private Task<bool> GeneratePartInfo(List<int> confIds)
        {
            bool _finished = true;

            while (loopTimes < (this.TotalConfTime / 1000))
            {
                foreach (int confId in confIds)
                {
                    Random partId = new Random();
                    var part = new PartInfo()
                    {
                        ConfId = confId.ToString(),
                        Connected = true,
                        PartId = partId.Next().ToString()
                    };

                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(m, part);
                        ActiveMQBytesMessage msg = new ActiveMQBytesMessage();
                        msg.Content = m.ToArray();
                        msg.Properties.SetString("confid", confId.ToString());

                        Interlocked.Increment(ref msgNum);
                        msg.Properties.SetString("msgNum", msgNum.ToString());

                        msg.NMSDeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;
                        msg.NMSType = "partinfo";
                        msg.NMSTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

                        msg.ReadOnlyBody = true;

                        var topic = new ActiveMQTopic(publishTopicName + "." + confId.ToString());

                        this.producer = this.sessionProducer.CreateProducer(topic);
                        this.producer.Send(msg);

                        loggerText.Enqueue(String.Format("{0} - MsgNum {1}: Sending PartInfo message for ConfId {2}, PartId {3}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), msgNum.ToString(), confId.ToString(), part.PartId));
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(PartInfoTime);
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(_finished);
        }

        private Task<bool> GenerateTalker(List<int> confIds)
        {
            bool _finished = true;

            while (loopTimes < (this.TotalConfTime / 1000))
            {
                foreach (int confId in confIds)
                {
                    var talker = new Talker()
                    {
                        ConfId = confId.ToString(),
                        PartIds = new List<string> { "xxxxxxx" }
                    };

                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(m, talker);
                        ActiveMQBytesMessage msg = new ActiveMQBytesMessage();
                        msg.Content = m.ToArray();
                        msg.Properties.SetString("confid", confId.ToString());

                        Interlocked.Increment(ref msgNum);
                        msg.Properties.SetString("msgNum", msgNum.ToString());

                        msg.NMSDeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;
                        msg.NMSType = "talker";
                        msg.NMSTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

                        msg.ReadOnlyBody = true;

                        var topic = new ActiveMQTopic(publishTopicName + "." + confId.ToString());

                        this.producer = this.sessionProducer.CreateProducer(topic);
                        this.producer.Send(msg);

                        loggerText.Enqueue(String.Format("{0} - MsgNum {1}: Sending Talker message for ConfId {2}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), msgNum.ToString(), confId.ToString()));
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(TalkerTime);
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(_finished);
        }

        private Task<bool> LoadConfig(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            bool _success = false;

            try
            {
                if (collection.Keys.Contains("EndpointString"))
                {
                    this.EndpointString = collection["EndpointString"];
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("TalkerSelected"))
                {
                    this.TalkerSelected = bool.Parse(collection["TalkerSelected"].ToArray()[0]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("TalkerTime"))
                {
                    this.TalkerTime = Int32.Parse(collection["TalkerTime"]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("PartInfoSelected"))
                {
                    this.PartInfoSelected = bool.Parse(collection["PartInfoSelected"].ToArray()[0]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("PartInfoTime"))
                {
                    this.PartInfoTime = Int32.Parse(collection["PartInfoTime"]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("ConfInfoSelected"))
                {
                    this.ConfInfoSelected = bool.Parse(collection["ConfInfoSelected"].ToArray()[0]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("ConfInfoTime"))
                {
                    this.ConfInfoTime = Int32.Parse(collection["ConfInfoTime"]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("TotalConfTime"))
                {
                    this.TotalConfTime = Int32.Parse(collection["TotalConfTime"]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("NumSimultaneousConfs"))
                {
                    this.NumSimultaneousConfs = Int32.Parse(collection["NumSimultaneousConfs"]);
                    ConfIds = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, NumSimultaneousConfs));
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConfIds", JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(ConfIds));
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("NumParts"))
                {
                    this.NumParts = Int32.Parse(collection["NumParts"]);
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("UserName"))
                {
                    this.UserName = collection["UserName"];
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("Password"))
                {
                    this.Password = collection["Password"];
                }

                if (collection.Keys.Contains("Logger"))
                {
                    this.Logger = collection["Logger"];
                }

                _success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            return Task.FromResult(_success);
        }
    }
```

Any help at all would be appreciated (even if its to tell me I'm being a moron)!

Answer (score 0):

So no matter how much I just wanted to leverage model binding the post event was killing me and it just doesn't seem possible without some really hacky solutions or something like SignalR to essentially live update the textarea. I decided to move on and use JavaScript and a setInterval to just check the data model every second.